# trigger click after redirection of a page-JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

when i click on a div in a page it redirects to different page and click should be triggered on that page.I tried the below code but its not working. please help me solve the issue

```
$('#leaderboardbutton').on('click',function(e){
    window.location='AVM-HomeScreen.html';
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#leaderboard').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: How can this possible while user redirects to another page?

Comment: You cannot do that. Don't forget that JS is client side. By the time you've called `window.location`, the execution of JS on the current page is stopped. There's no way to trigger on a click `AVM-HomeScreen.html` from within another page...

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com  there is a button in AVM-HomeScreen.html which has to be clicked by default when i redirect to this page.

Comment: You have to trigger the click in the target page, not in the current page where you clicked the link

Comment: @BenM Thanks.. can i know anyother  possible solution ?

Comment: How javascript will no that I've to trigger the click event on redirected page if you  have not passed any parameter to do that?

Comment: Pass a GET parameter, check for that parameter on the new page, if it is set trigger the click.

Comment: @user3044827 Check my answer. It's along similar lines to what is suggested above.

Answer (score 6):

If you have to click a button contained within `AVM-HomeScreen.html`, you'll need to pass some kind of tracking parameter. For example:

```
$('#leaderboardbutton').on('click',function(e){
    window.location='AVM-HomeScreen.html?click=true';
});
```

Next, on `AVM-HomeScreen.html`, you'll need to check if `click == true`, and then trigger. For example adding the following JS to `AVM-HomeScreen.html` should achieve what you need:

```
if(getParameterByName('click') == 'true')
{
    $('#leaderboard').trigger('click');
}

function getParameterByName(name) 
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: window.location='AVM-HomeScreen.html?click=true'; There is no link with click true. It wont redirect to this page right ?

Comment: Yes, it will redirect. `?click=true` is a URL parameter, not part of the filename...

Comment: No problem. You might want to accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: buts not working.

I have included the following code.

$('#leaderboardbutton').on('click',function(e){
    window.location='AVM-HomeScreen.html?click=true';
 fun1();
});

function fun1()
{

 if(getParameterByName('click') == 'true')
{

    $('#leaderboard').trigger('click');
}
function getParameterByName(name) 
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

}

Comment: there is problem after u redirect .The IF condition is not getting called.

Comment: Help please.. Its urgent. Thanks in advance

Comment: I know. Please read the answer carefully. You need to place the redirect on one page, and the second code portion on `AVM-HomeScreen.html`. They shouldn't both be on the same page.